# how to make nested div with CSS only

Tags: css, nested, styles

Given the follow html and css, how to make the nested box like the

```
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'></div>
```

Comment: Where is your css that is trying to do so?

Comment: @B001ᛦ The solution I can think of is to add a nested div html element and then style that nested div to make it center in the parent div, but the requirement is to use css only, and I don't know how .

Answer (score 1):

draw them using background:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background:
    /* color                   position             / width height*/
    linear-gradient(red   0 0) left  20px top    20px/50px   50px,
    linear-gradient(green 0 0) right 30px top    20px/50px   50px,
    linear-gradient(blue  0 0) left  40px bottom 40px/50px   50px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `before` or `after` pseudo element in CSS to achieve what you're looking for without altering the HTML at all. Take a look:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parent::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'></div>
```

Comment: Hi John! Thanks for the solution. I wonder if it's possible to create a pseudo element inside the .parent::before? For example, I want to have two other boxes display inside the black box.

Comment: In which case, @Angie, update your question (using the 'edit' link) to explain exactly what you want, don't leave comments that - essentially - ask for just a little bit more.

Comment: @John! Apologize! I just updated my questions.